# Discord.js How to add new user to channel permissions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to add new user to channel permissions.

I don't use **updateOverwrite()** because it only changes the permissions and I don't use **overwritePermissions()** because it clears other users/roles. I want like this:

> Channel Permissions:
>
> User1: Allow: Type Messages

channel.function_i_need(user.id) //Add new user to channel permissions.

channel.updateOverwrite(user.id, {"VIEW_MESSAGES": true}) //Change the permissions of user.

> Channel Permissions
>
> User1: Allow: Type Messages
>
> User2: Allow: View Messages

Is possible to do like it?

Comment: `updateOverwrite` by itself will do the job, as it creates overwrites if they do not exist already.

Comment: Sorry, it was another problem.